# Pyppeteer get stuck in a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, pyppeteer

I am using Pyppeteer to get web content, and it runs normally with FastAPI on this machine. However, when placed in a Docker container, it will get stuck in the newPage function. Below is my code.

main.py

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pyppeteer import launch

app = FastAPI()

async def test():
  browser = await launch(
    args=[
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    ]
  )
  page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto("https://example.com")
  await page.waitForSelector(".invoice-box")
  bodyHandle = await page.querySelector("body")
  body = await bodyHandle.boundingBox()
  pageWidth = round(body["width"])
  pageHeight = round(body["height"])
  await page.setViewport({"width": pageWidth, "height": pageHeight})
  await page.screenshot({"path": "example.png", "fullPage": True})
  await browser.close()

@app.get("/test")
async def main():
  await test()
  return {"message": "ok"}
```

Due to project requirements, I chose this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs).

Dockerfile

```
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.11-nodejs18-slim

WORKDIR /code

COPY entrypoint.sh requirements.txt /code/

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libpango-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
        libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
        libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
        libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
        ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget \
        xvfb x11vnc x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable x11-apps \
    && chmod +x entrypoint-dev.sh

COPY app /code/app

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to launch Pyppeteer the first time it tries to install suitable chromium, if not found in that cotainer (as they mentioned in their docs [usage](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer#usage) section).

If you want to avoid this, add this command after all `apt-get` commands:

```
RUN pyppeteer-install
```

However, I will strongly recommend not use Pyppeteer inside celery or an other process, not use inside web api.